# I parked outside the entrance of/to the building

Tags: prepositions

> I parked outside the entrance of/to the building.

Are both correct and mean the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

I think yes, both do mean the same thing, of is relating/pointing to the building and to is also pointing to the building, both words are pointing to the building and so they mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Q. **I parked outside the entrance of/to the building**. *Are both correct and mean the same thing?*

**My Answer**; Yes

---

**I parked outside the entrance of the building**

**of**; preposition (POSSESSION): used to show possession, belonging, or origin:

I parked outside the entrance **belonging to** the building

---

**I parked outside the entrance to the building**

**to** preposition (BELONGING); matching or belonging to:

I parked outside the entrance **belonging to** the building

All ref CED [OF](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/of)

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically they're different, because in *the entrance to the building* the *to* phrase is a complement, which supplies part of the meaning of "entrance"; whereas *of the building* is an adjunct, supplying supplementary information about the entrance.

But I can't think of a case where there is a difference in meaning. *Entrance to* seems to be more common than *entrance of*, but not hugely so (758:533 in the iWeb corpus).

I think that where the focus of attention is the entrance, you're more likely to say *entrance to*; but when the focus is the building, and the entrance is being mentioned in passing, then *entrance of* might be as common (though *to* would still be possible).